# Help to understand the usage of "after" in "Nothing you need to get a chain saw after yet"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

> Wareheim said so far the wind has only knocked down branches and limbs small enough to be carried. "Nothing you need to get a chain saw **after** yet," he said by phone.

As I understand, the sentence is saying that: *Nothing you need to get a chain saw **after the hurricane is gone** yet*.  But I'm not sure if my understanding is correct?

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/news/hurricane-florence-pummels-carolinas-residents-shelter-143010592.html).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To me, this seems like an unusual usage of phrasal verb *get after*:

> [get after](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+after)
>   2. To pursue something that is a problem or menace: If you don't get after those termites, your house will be destroyed.
>   (TFD)

You *get after [someone/something] (with something)*. Wareheim's usage strikes me as a (US) Southernism, and the article does state that the man has a home in North Carolina.

The usual construction would be

> Nothing you need to **get after** *with a chainsaw* yet.
>   (complete sentence) → [There is] nothing you need to get after with a chainsaw yet.

In other words, there is nothing yet that needs to be handled, cleared, or destroyed with a chainsaw.

Comment: "get on to" or "get on top of" are similar non literal constructs which I find are used more commonly.

Comment: In the context of hurricane Florence, meaning this is the US east coast round about the Carolinas, this is not an unusual usage. <big wide grin>

Answer (score 9):

So far [*yet*, before some more severe destruction] there's nothing to go [get] **after** with a chain saw.

**P. S.** Anyway, *after* points here at the *source of trouble* needing a chain saw to be applied. *Go after* means 'to try to find' (e.g. to go after gold), to aim at something needing application of that instrument here. As the other answer shows, the original *get after* expression has an even more direct meaning *addressing something troublesome* (with that instrument here).

Answer (score 4):

Another way of wording that sentence: So far there has been nothing that needed a chainsaw used on it before it could be removed.

After is being used in the sense of “applied to”.

Answer (score 2):

We can **get after** something that needs tending or requires our action. That is,  we see that the thing gets done. We tend to the matter.

> I need to get after the backed-up laundry now that the washing machine has been repaired.

We can also get *someone* after something:

> We need to get the dog-catcher after these packs of stray dogs.

And, in an extended, somewhat joking sense, we can **get** *something* **after** something:

> I need to get the rake after those dead leaves.

That is, **I** need to rake those leaves. The rake, being an inanimate object, cannot be given an assignment or a task to complete as the dog-catcher can.

And we can **get after** *something* **with** something.

> You need to get after those tall weeds with a sickle. A lawn mower won't do.

Comment: So, can the original sentence be understood as "*Nothing you need to get a chain saw after branches and limbs yet*"?

Comment: @dan: Your paraphrase is not a grammatical sentence. It can be understood as *There is nothing, so far, for which you would need a chain saw.* Or in a more colloquial register, *There is nothing, so far, you would need to take a chain saw to.*  See `take sth to sth`.

Comment: *Get down outta that tree, or I'll take a switch to your sorry ass.*

Comment: I made an analogy to your example: "I need to get the rake after those dead leaves."

Comment: Compare "get a chain saw after branches and limbs" to "get the rake after those dead leaves", I don't understand why the latter is right and the former is wrong.

Comment: @dan "Nothing you need to get the rake after those dead leaves" is also... wrong or awkward or nonsensical. But on its own, "Get a chain saw after [those] branches and limbs" sounds fine.

Comment: @mattdm Hah, that's interesting. Standing alone is fine, while awkward in a sentence.

Comment: Well, just awkward when put into that particular sentence in the way you did. Like "Nothing you need from the store milk and bread yet?"

Comment: @mattdm I think I understand you now. It looks like "nothing" stands for "branches and limbs" in that sentence, so they clash with each other in that sentence. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's it. The branches *are* nothing (to be concerned about).

Comment: @dan: Your statement is ungrammatical because you're providing two objects ("Nothing" and "branches and limbs") to the phrasal verb. Please ask a separate question about your paraphrase as the explanation cannot fit in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think it looks like an unusual usage of the word **after**. It looks like it could simply be substituted with a **for**.

Nothing you need to get a chainsaw **for** yet.

In other words:
After the winds as of yet, theres nothing you can't take care of without a chainsaw.